# h264_mp4toannexb filter failed to receive output packet while ffmpeg concat

Tags: ffmpeg, video-processing, video-editing

I am writing a very easy concat script for a list of videos.

`(for %i in (*.mp4) do @echo file '%i') > mylist.txt`

`ffmpeg -safe 0 -f concat -i mylist.txt -c copy merged.mp4`

Yet the log says something weird `h264_mp4toannexb filter failed to receive output packet”`
Those files are rendered in VLC, but at certain timestamps they start to disallow moving the playtime cursor. I suspect that might be the case but I do not see much from the failed files.

The file(s) it fails on has the following description (`ffmpeg -i fn.mp4`)
[image]

EDIT: Truncated stats from all of the files in order.

```
[{'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2715 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1664 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1438 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1473 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1479 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1502 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1514 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1581 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1600 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1814 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1136 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1747 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1872 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1538 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 2839 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1595 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1733 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1623 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1634 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1564 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1635 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1674 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1809 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1650 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1773 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1643 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1802 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1766 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1809 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1641 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1812 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1984 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1787 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1912 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1839 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1903 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1826 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1900 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1773 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1799 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1933 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 2023 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1971 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 2071 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1997 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1692 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1785 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1864 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 2007 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1897 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1726 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1799 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1683 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1735 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1751 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 2003 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1208 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1497 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1591 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1662 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1747 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1634 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1891 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1734 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1998 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1997 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1752 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1695 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 2002 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1934 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1799 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1966 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1972 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1968 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 2144 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 2049:2048 DAR 683:384], 1937 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)'},
 {'Stream #0:0': '    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1674 kb/s, 29.99 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn, 60 tbc (default)',
  'Stream #0:1': '    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)'}]
```

Comment: Do all files have video as the first stream and are all video streams h264?

Comment: I have added the stats for all of the files. It seems that all of the videos are fine - the first stream and h264.

Comment: This is one of the "broken" files.  https://gofile.io/?c=ti2w80 I checked at what mp4 the error is thrown. There are several files like that.

Comment: This is one of the files that work fine. https://gofile.io/?c=okKK4C

Comment: The broken file has a corrupt packet in the video stream.

Comment: Is there a way to ignore the corrupt packets when merging the videos? Since the video still contains 99% correct  packets.

Comment: Or maybe could you please help with writing a script that can check which packets and where are corrupt? simple ```ffmpeg -i clip.mp4``` doesn't show any corruptions, well since it's simply metadata of the file.

Comment: `ffmpeg -i clip.mp4 -c copy -an -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f null -`

Comment: I am not sure since I get all the same results as when I run `ffmpeg -i clip.mp4` except that it returns `Trailing options were found on the commandline` from your command

Comment: There are no trailing options in my command. Verify your command string matches mine. Add -report at the end and share report if you still get error.

Comment: You were right. I didn't copy the `-` at the end that was important. It shows that there is a broken packet at the frame 1742. Is it possible to ignore (discard) that frame (such frame) and keep the rest before and after when I want to concatenate the clips? i.e. I would like to keep as much as possible from the clips when concatenating. This is the `-report` output of one of the broken clips. https://gofile.io/?c=oysEmz

Comment: @Gyan I have tried doing that for another bunch of videos and I cannot understand what is wrong here. All of the files seem to be working well. But the combined one (the last one _merged.mp4) is totally broken in length. I ran the test on all of the files here. https://gofile.io/?c=g3TiNl

Comment: Any ideas? I have the same issue. I have videos that play correctly, but concat is unable to concatenate them. ffmpeg version 4.3.1-4ubuntu1

Comment: Did someone find how to ignore these errors to still merge the videos ?

Comment: Also interested in a solution that allows skipping the corrupt packets, as if you transcoded the problematic file to a new one (which succeeds) and concatenated that, but without multiple commands @Gyan